# Django QuerySet Filter no result when looking up a string containing a point

Tags: python, django-queryset

I am not sure if I may googled wrong or if I just can't see my mistake.

I am using Django 3.x with a postgreSQL Database with a schema called django2.

I have a Model in Django containing a CharField to save an IPv4 Address. Yes I know about GenericIPAddressField and may switch to that.

```
class APN(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    username= models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    responsible_user= models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I want to filter with `results_apn = APN.objects.filter(ip__contains=query)` where `query` is a string.

Filtering the QuerySet on `ip__contains=query` leads me to two observations:

1. when looking up for a number without any dots (e.g. 100 or 254) then I'll get all IPs containing that particular string
2. whenn looking up a part of an IP or the full IP (e.g. 10.171.16.14 or 17.128) then I'll get no results.

I got the query that Django generates (QuerySet.query):

```
SELECT "sim_apn"."address", "sim_apn"."username", "sim_apn"."password", "sim_apn"."ip", "sim_apn"."responsible_user", "sim_apn"."assigned" FROM "sim_apn" WHERE "sim_apn"."ip"::text LIKE %10.171.16.14%
```

Ad If I'll use this directly in SQL then I am getting a result. But Django does not want to give me an answer to that.

Am I missing something or does Django have problems with points in filter queries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are few obvious questions that I have to ask, are you sure the objects you're looking for; actually exist?

Like you said, `GenericIPAddressField` is your best bet to store IPs

I don't think `icontains` would make any difference but try it.

If you need an urgent hotfix, a hacky (not recommended) way to get it to work is by splitting the IP, filter all the results that contain the first number, then narrow it down and filter the second number.

For example: IP 127.67.1.1

ip_split = ['127','67','1','1']

Get a query list of all results that contain ip_split[0] then filter it down if they don't contain the rest of the ip fractions.

Hacky, but it'll work until you figure out a Pythonic way to fix it.

Comment: Yes, the objects are in the DB. There are around 1200 entrys with IPs. And the same query done by hand is returning the wanted results. 

Then I will try to change the field to `GenericIPAddressField`. It should run in a productive enviroment in near future, so the hotfix is not the way I can do it.